# Resolve data for 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Let's say, I have 3 tables. "users", "topics" and "replies.

The "topics" and "replies" table do have a column "user_id" which references to "id" on the "users" table. The "replies" table also have a column "topic_id" which references "id" on "topics". Also imagine that each topic has 1 reply.

Now, I want to fetch all topics and resolve the username for both tables, so the output should include a "topic_username" and a "reply_username".

I know how to select the username for the topic, but how can I do that for both the topics and replies table?

Thanks

Updated code:

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   t_users.username as topic_user,
   last_reply.user_id as last_reply_user_id,
   r_users.username as last_reply_username,
   last_reply.replies_count,

ORDER BY IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at DESC

FROM

   topics as t
   left join users as t_users on t_users.id = t.user_id
   left join ( select r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies order by id desc) as r group by r.topic_id ) as last_reply on last_reply.topic_id = t.id
   left join users as r_users on r_users.id = last_reply.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   t_users.name as topic_user,
   r_users.name as reply_user
FROM
   topics as t
   left join replies as r on r.topic_id=t.id
   left join users as t_users on t_users.id = t.user_id
   left join users as r_users on r_users.id = r.user_id
```

this would work well if there is 1:1 topic and reply, if you have 1 to many replies then you are better off group by topic id and get the usernames by group concat

Version 2 (to get reply count and last reply user)

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   t_users.name as topic_user,
   last_reply.user_id as last_reply_user_id,
   r_users.name as last_reply_username,
   last_reply.replies_count,
   IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) as last_update

FROM

   topics as t
   left join users as t_users on t_users.id = t.user_id
   left join ( select r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies order by id desc) as r group by r.topic_id ) as last_reply on last_reply.topic_id = t.id
   left join users as r_users on r_users.id = last_reply.user_id

ORDER BY IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) DESC
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to do that as well? I am not very familar with joins. What I want in the end is that I get a result that containts all topics, the amount of replies to each of them as "replies_count" and the username and id as "topic_username", "topic_user_id", reply_username" and "reply_user_id". The topic with the most recent reply should be at the top, and then descending (timestamp for reply creation is replies.created_at.) If there is no reply, the topic.created_at should be used. I am stuck at this since almost 2 days now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Besides the fact, that your query looks ten times better than what I currently have, I am getting a: #1054 - Unknown column 't_users.name' in 'field list'

Comment: t_user.name is the field that has the user's name in the users table. you should change it to t_user.fullname or whatever you have in your user table

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to order by "created_at" to get the latest reply correctly, but now it works perfectly. I just need to add 2 more things, I hope I can figure that out on my own. Will update you asap. Thank you very much!

Comment: If I also want to include the created_at as "topic_created_at" and "latest_reply_created_at", where would I put that? I tried to add that add the top but that give me an error. I don't want to create another subqueries for that if it possible without doing so. THat's the last 2 things I would need. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I also just saw that this sub query `` select * from replies order by created_at desc`` seelcts all replies. Is there a way to limit that to the required ones? Because if there are thousands of replies than this will overload the db if a couple clients load the forums.

Comment: try  `IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) as last_update`

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean? Use that inside a join? This complicated query is confusing me quite a lot sadly.

Comment: Thank you. It's almost working. The problem currently is that the last_reply_created_at is not correct. It does not take the latest one.

Comment: I also added a SORT BY to make sure that the topics with the most recent reply are at the topic , but without the correct "last_reply_created_at" it won't work. Pleas elet me know if this is not required (i mean the order by at the end). I updated the code in the question.

Comment: you can `order by IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at)`

Comment: I updated the code. YOu mean like that? Cause that is causing an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94526/discussion-between-michael-and-shujaat).

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do this in a single query? You can do it like this but I believe a separate query for fetching replies and topics might be better (fetch replies first, get the unique topic IDs and then fetch topics in a separate query)

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.topic_id, ru.username AS reply_username, tu.username AS topic_username
FROM replies AS r
    INNER JOIN topics AS t ON (t.id = r.topic_id)
    INNER JOIN users AS ru ON (r.user_id = u.id)
    INNER JOIN users AS tu ON (t.user_id = u.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly I need to do it in one query. Please see above comment to see what I am trying to do. Thank you

Comment: Do you simply want to fetch the reply count or each reply's username as well?

Comment: Both. The count of the replies for each topic should be called "replies_count" and the username and id as "topic_username", "topic_user_id", reply_username" and "reply_user_id".

Comment: My current query is: 
``
select `topics`.`id` as `topic_id`, `topics`.`created_at` as `topic_created_at`, MAX(replies.created_at) as reply_created_at, `topics`.`title`, `users`.`id` as `user_id`, `users`.*, (select COUNT(*) from replies where topics.id = replies.topic_id) reply_count from `topics` inner join `users` on `topics`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `replies` on `topics`.`id` = `replies`.`topic_id` where `topics`.`category_id` = 2 group by `topics`.`id`
``
But I have the feeling that this is overcomplicated.

Comment: Not really, that looks about right (formatting is off so I just had a quick look). Ideally this should be split into two (one for topic and other for replies).

Comment: No idea why it doe snot accept my code tags. Well, it works, but it does not include the username and id for the topic creator and the one who posted the latest reply, that is my issue. Sadly i can't split it up, I need it in one query due to technical limitations.